# I have grid and hyperlink column inside it. How to prevent redirect if come condition is true?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, grid

This hyper link column show some counters. And if count is 0 i write "N/A" inside this column. I need transform this cell from hyper link to regular text or maybe something else. Main idea of this, this field should not look like hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the hyperlink to not follow the link, you must return false on the javascript event `onclick`

On the asp.net you can do that as:

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" OnClientClick="return CanIGo();" />
```

and with javascript

```
<script>
function CanIGo()
{
   if(contitionToAllowClick)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
</script>
```

The rest part of the user interface is left to you. You can show a message, change the style and make it look as text, or what ever you like.